# How to retrieve ALL the images saved in a SQLite db into a layout?

Tags: android, xml, image, sqlite, layout

In my android project, i have saved camera snapshots along with some description in a SQLite database. Now i want to retrieve all those images plus the description one by one and view them in a xml layout that i have created.

here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 


android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Data" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showIv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/marker_default" 
        />"

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i tried  following code snippets seperatly,

```
 String[] columns = new String[]{"_id", "name","description","image"};
    Cursor c = myDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.getCount()>0){
    c.moveToNext();
    byte[] data = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image"));
    return data;
    }else{
    return null;
```

//i converted the byte array to bitmap and displayed on the layout

```
String result = "";
    int iname= c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int ides= c.getColumnIndex("description");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showTv);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {                    
    result += c.getString(iname) + c.getString(ides);    

    }
    return result;
```

---

but i want to get both image and the description together for ALL the data.
please suggest me a method to all the Images and description one by one.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout you made won't support more than one Image. Since there is only one ImageView. Unless you want to do a lot of image manipulation, that is. So you should choose an View that fits your needs. I would look at the Gallery widget or ListView widget. Then you need to create a cursor adapter that will adapt the data from your database to your Gallery or Listview widget.

Take a look at:
[listview with sqllite](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/android-using-the-sqlite-database-with-listview/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Samuel, im a newbie to android and i've been searching a proper example for 3 days. Thanks again for your link.